# mysql fails on ALTER TABLE constraint: Can't create table (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE face_group (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(100), description     VARCHAR(200), pivotxpos FLOAT(18, 2) NOT NULL, pivotypos FLOAT(18, 2) NOT NULL, created_at        DATETIME NOT NULL, updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE = INNODB;
CREATE TABLE face_image (id bigint NOT NULL, imageurl VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, created_at DATETIME NOT NULL, updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL) ENGINE = INNODB;
CREATE TABLE face_tag (id bigint NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(100), tagtype VARCHAR(100), created_at DATETIME NOT NULL, updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL) ENGINE = INNODB;
CREATE TABLE grouped_feature (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, feature_id bigint NOT NULL, face_group_id bigint NOT NULL, pivotxposoverride FLOAT(18, 2) NOT   NULL, pivotyposoverride FLOAT(18, 2) NOT NULL, created_at DATETIME NOT NULL, updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL, INDEX face_group_id_idx (face_group_id), INDEX feature_id_idx            (feature_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE = INNODB;
CREATE TABLE tagged_face (id bigint NOT NULL, face_image_id bigint NOT NULL, face_tag_id bigint NOT NULL, tag_value VARCHAR(100), created_at DATETIME NOT NULL, updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL, INDEX face_image_id_idx (face_image_id), INDEX face_tag_id_idx (face_tag_id)) ENGINE = INNODB;
CREATE TABLE tweaked_curve (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, tweaked_feature_id bigint NOT NULL, curve_id bigint NOT NULL, created_at DATETIME NOT NULL, updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL,     INDEX tweaked_feature_id_idx (tweaked_feature_id), INDEX curve_id_idx (curve_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE = INNODB;
CREATE TABLE tweaked_feature (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, face_group_id bigint NOT NULL, feature_id bigint NOT NULL, face_image_id bigint NOT NULL, pivotxpos FLOAT(18, 2) NOT NULL,  pivotypos FLOAT(18, 2) NOT NULL, created_at DATETIME NOT NULL, updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL, INDEX face_group_id_idx (face_group_id), INDEX feature_id_idx (feature_id), INDEX      face_image_id_idx (face_image_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE = INNODB;
CREATE TABLE tweaked_point (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, tweaked_curve_id bigint NOT NULL, point_id bigint NOT NULL, xposoverride FLOAT(18, 2) NOT NULL, yposoverride FLOAT(18, 2) NOT NULL, user_tweaked TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, created_at DATETIME NOT NULL, updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL, INDEX tweaked_curve_id_idx (tweaked_curve_id), INDEX point_id_idx   (point_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE = INNODB;
ALTER TABLE grouped_feature ADD CONSTRAINT grouped_feature_feature_id_feature_id FOREIGN KEY (feature_id) REFERENCES feature(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE grouped_feature ADD CONSTRAINT grouped_feature_face_group_id_face_group_id FOREIGN KEY (face_group_id) REFERENCES face_group(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE tagged_face ADD CONSTRAINT tagged_face_face_tag_id_face_tag_id FOREIGN KEY (face_tag_id) REFERENCES face_tag(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE tagged_face ADD CONSTRAINT tagged_face_face_image_id_face_image_id FOREIGN KEY (face_image_id) REFERENCES face_image(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE tweaked_curve ADD CONSTRAINT tweaked_curve_tweaked_feature_id_tweaked_feature_id FOREIGN KEY (tweaked_feature_id) REFERENCES tweaked_feature(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE tweaked_curve ADD CONSTRAINT tweaked_curve_curve_id_curve_id FOREIGN KEY (curve_id) REFERENCES curve(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE tweaked_feature ADD CONSTRAINT tweaked_feature_feature_id_feature_id FOREIGN KEY (feature_id) REFERENCES feature(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE tweaked_feature ADD CONSTRAINT tweaked_feature_face_image_id_face_image_id FOREIGN KEY (face_image_id) REFERENCES face_image(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE tweaked_feature ADD CONSTRAINT tweaked_feature_face_group_id_face_group_id FOREIGN KEY (face_group_id) REFERENCES face_group(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE tweaked_point ADD CONSTRAINT tweaked_point_tweaked_curve_id_tweaked_curve_id FOREIGN KEY (tweaked_curve_id) REFERENCES tweaked_curve(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE tweaked_point ADD CONSTRAINT tweaked_point_point_id_point_id FOREIGN KEY (point_id) REFERENCES point(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

And the ALTER TABLE tagged_face command fails with a strange "can't create table error 150" error.

I've looked at other posts regarding this issue but I don't see what I'm doing wrong (foreign keys reference columns of the same type and that are unique). Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `face_image` table has no index. An index is required to police the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint.

Add an index on the `face_image` table and you should be set ...

Answer (score 1):

I think it all fails here:

```
REFERENCES feature(id)
```

Maybe you have to reference to:

```
REFERENCES grouped_feature(id)
```

Or

```
REFERENCES tweaked_feature(id)
```

Tested on my local mysql database.